# Show $\dfrac{x}{x+y} \in (0, 1/2)$ or $(1/2, 1)$ depending on whether $x < y$ or $y > x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Suppose I have two positive numbers $x, y$.

Obviously $$q=\dfrac{x}{x+y} \in (0, 1)$$
since $x + y > x$, implying $\dfrac{x+y}{x} > 1$ and thus $\dfrac{x}{x+y} < 1$. This is bounded below by $0$ is because a quotient of positive numbers is positive (or maybe there's some other reason, but this is irrelevant for the crux of my question).

**Consider two cases: $x > y$ and $x < y$. What happens to $q$?**

**Apparently $q \in (0, 1/2)$ in one case, and $q \in (1/2, 1)$ in another, but it isn't clear to me *how* this would be shown. Particularly, how is this bound of $1/2$ derived?**

I suppose we could take two positive numbers, say $3 > 2$ and set $y = 3$ and $x = 2$. Then $q = \dfrac{2}{5} \in (0, 1/2)$ - so this suggests that when $y > x$, then $q \in (0, 1/2)$ (most likely). If we take $x = 3$ and $y = 2$, then $q = \dfrac{3}{5} = 0.6 \in (1/2, 1)$. So this suggests
$$q \in (0, 1/2)\text{ when } y > x$$
and 
$$q \in (1/2, 1) \text{ when } x > y$$
but I can't think of any way of actually showing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :-

Case 1. When $y>x\implies \frac{x}{x+y}<\frac{x}{x+x}=\frac{1}{2}$.

Similarly the other case follows.

Comment: So, it looks like I should go to bed. I'll mark your answer as best in the morning. Thank you!

Comment: @Clarinetist glad to help !!

Comment: Sorry, what do you do for the other case? We have x/(x+y) > y/(x+y), then

Comment: Sorry, figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$\frac{x}{x+y} +\frac{y}{x+y} =1 \\
\frac{x}{x+y} > \frac{y}{x+y} \Leftrightarrow x >y$$